# Android Seekbar position thumb to the right of a vertical seekbar

Tags: android

I have a vertical seek bar in my layout, and I want to position the thumb to the right of the seek bar. At the moment it displays to the left. Can I change this? Below is a screenshot and my xml:

```
    <co.za.datasolve.verticalslider.VerticalSeekBar
            android:id="@+id/sb_alcohol"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/five"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:thumb="@drawable/slider_pin"
            android:max="220"
            android:minWidth="200sp"
            android:maxWidth="200sp"
            android:progress="0"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_alcohol_progress" />
```

[image]

I need to display the image to the right hand side instead of the left. Do you have any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @pskink The top left image with a white border. I want it aligned to the right. That is a vertical seekbar